# facebook android integration not working for share with friends

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have made a simple program in android for facebook android integaration,I have tried as below:it shows facebook login dialog box and successfully logged in after that it also shows myapp and ask to share it with my facebook friends but when i press"yes"..it says failed to post on wall"....please tell me whats the problem,,
my code is as below:

**main.java**

```
package com.example.facbk;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String APP_ID = "454641867918042";
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};

    private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
        private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
        private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";

    private Facebook facebook;
    private String messageToPost;

    public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
            System.out.println("hello token");
            System.out.println(facebook.getAccessToken());
            return editor.commit();

        }

        public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
            facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
            return facebook.isSessionValid();
        }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        restoreCredentials(facebook);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
        if (facebookMessage == null){
            facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
        }
        messageToPost = facebookMessage;
    }

    public void doNotShare(View button){
        finish();
    }
    public void share(View button){
        if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            loginAndPostToWall();
        }
        else {
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
    }

    public void loginAndPostToWall(){
         facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
    }

    public void postToWall(String message){
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", message);
                parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
                try {
                    facebook.request("me");
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                    response.equals("false")) {
                showToast("Blank response.");
            }
            else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            }
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }

    class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            saveCredentials(facebook);
            if (messageToPost != null){
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
        }
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onCancel() {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
07-11 18:45:55.200: E/libEGL(1006): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-11 18:45:55.200: D/ShaderProgram(1006): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-11 18:45:55.211: E/libEGL(1006): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-11 18:45:55.211: D/ShaderProgram(1006): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-11 18:45:55.211: E/libEGL(1006): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-11 18:45:55.211: D/ShaderProgram(1006): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-11 18:45:55.211: E/libEGL(1006): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-11 18:45:55.221: D/ShaderProgram(1006): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-11 18:45:55.221: E/libEGL(1006): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-11 18:45:55.221: D/ShaderProgram(1006): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-11 18:46:12.610: D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(1006): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/confirm
07-11 18:46:14.720: D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(1006): Redirect URL: fbconnect://success#access_token=CAAGdfo8JitoBAEAs1rWo2oDZCG4JVSeoqV4HxmZBLHkrVgZCjDlX07bFVMy7fOmRA1VbNXTC0oTPNVMagcZCbXS3wQsA4bAkoEwdd7atG8VKZBOYR6ClAFZCYZAVDGUpz1kbMTLAl99VauZAzXswbsBe&expires_in=5157278
07-11 18:46:15.370: D/dalvikvm(1006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 427K, 6% free 9524K/10055K, paused 7ms+26ms
07-11 18:46:15.831: I/System.out(1006): hello token
07-11 18:46:15.831: I/System.out(1006): CAAGdfo8JitoBAEAs1rWo2oDZCG4JVSeoqV4HxmZBLHkrVgZCjDlX07bFVMy7fOmRA1VbNXTC0oTPNVMagcZCbXS3wQsA4bAkoEwdd7atG8VKZBOYR6ClAFZCYZAVDGUpz1kbMTLAl99VauZAzXswbsBe
07-11 18:46:15.910: D/Facebook-Util(1006): GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAAGdfo8JitoBAEAs1rWo2oDZCG4JVSeoqV4HxmZBLHkrVgZCjDlX07bFVMy7fOmRA1VbNXTC0oTPNVMagcZCbXS3wQsA4bAkoEwdd7atG8VKZBOYR6ClAFZCYZAVDGUpz1kbMTLAl99VauZAzXswbsBe&format=json
07-11 18:46:16.030: W/System.err(1006): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-11 18:46:16.061: W/System.err(1006):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
07-11 18:46:16.061: W/System.err(1006):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
07-11 18:46:16.061: W/System.err(1006):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
07-11 18:46:16.070: W/System.err(1006):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
07-11 18:46:16.070: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
07-11 18:46:16.070: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
07-11 18:46:16.081: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
07-11 18:46:16.081: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
07-11 18:46:16.081: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
07-11 18:46:16.081: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
07-11 18:46:16.091: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
07-11 18:46:16.091: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
07-11 18:46:16.091: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
07-11 18:46:16.091: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
07-11 18:46:16.100: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
07-11 18:46:16.110: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
07-11 18:46:16.110: W/System.err(1006):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
07-11 18:46:16.120: W/System.err(1006):     at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:219)
07-11 18:46:16.120: W/System.err(1006):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:806)
07-11 18:46:16.130: W/System.err(1006):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:732)
07-11 18:46:16.130: W/System.err(1006):     at com.example.facbk.MainActivity.postToWall(MainActivity.java:93)
07-11 18:46:16.130: W/System.err(1006):     at com.example.facbk.MainActivity$LoginDialogListener.onComplete(MainActivity.java:115)
07-11 18:46:16.140: W/System.err(1006):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.onSessionCallback(Facebook.java:345)
07-11 18:46:16.140: W/System.err(1006):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.access$11(Facebook.java:326)
07-11 18:46:16.140: W/System.err(1006):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook$1.call(Facebook.java:304)
07-11 18:46:16.151: W/System.err(1006):     at com.facebook.Session$3$1.run(Session.java:1190)
07-11 18:46:16.151: W/System.err(1006):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-11 18:46:16.151: W/System.err(1006):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 18:46:16.160: W/System.err(1006):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 18:46:16.160: W/System.err(1006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-11 18:46:16.171: W/System.err(1006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 18:46:16.181: W/System.err(1006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 18:46:16.181: W/System.err(1006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-11 18:46:16.191: W/System.err(1006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-11 18:46:16.191: W/System.err(1006):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 18:46:19.750: I/jdwp(1006): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: post your StackTrace here

Comment: i already have posted it in my question..!

Comment: @dd619-i have posted my logcat ..pleasecheck it..!

Comment: @user2045570-please see my logcat....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

The first is that you're using a deprecated version of the Facebook SDK. If you're using 3.0.x of the SDK, please do not use the Facebook class, and use the Session and Request classes instead. See https://developers.facebook.com/android/ for tutorials and samples. But this doesn't actually affect correctness, which brings me to ...

Your issue is that you're doing a network request on the main thread (exactly as the exception says). What you need to do is to wrap your Facebook.request call inside an AsyncTask's doInBackground method.